# Android: Unable to download from play store

Tags: android

I am developing an Android App. I was able test it on my device successfully. So I pushed the released version on Google Play store. Now I uninstalled the debug build from my device and tried to download it from the Play Store. But when I click on install button, I am getting this error.

> you cannot install this app because another user has already installed
>   an incompatible version on this device...

[image]

I am only using Google Play services. Not using any storage or anything that might be different for different users and Android L. What changes should I make in my app source to resolve this?

**Edit**

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.unary.untangleit"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Did you place any restrictions in the manifest to restrict your app to certain types of phones?

Comment: Can you try clearing the app data of google play app and try

Comment: @iRuth I guess no. Please see the edit.

Comment: Do you have multiple users for the device?

Comment: Have you trued going in under every user and deleting the app?

Comment: I removed app data, updates and cache in Google Play Store and it doesn't help. But I found solution, see link http://www.problogbooster.com/2014/10/Unknown-Error-Code-During-Application-Install-24-play-store-app-installation.html

Comment: Here is the answer that you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250/you-cannot-install-this-app-because-another-user-has-already-installed-an-incom#

Comment: check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250/you-cannot-install-this-app-because-another-user-has-already-installed-an-incom

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250/you-cannot-install-this-app-because-another-user-has-already-installed-an-incom/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue by uninstalling debug version of the app and then clearing data of play store app.

If this still doesn't work, you can follow these [steps given in this site](http://www.problogbooster.com/2014/10/Unknown-Error-Code-During-Application-Install-24-play-store-app-installation.html).

> Go to any root file manager, and navigate to directory: root >>
>   data/data folder.
>
> Find the relevant folder of that app which you were installing from
>   play store.
>
> Then delete that folder. [Note: Here you will loose all data related
>   to that app].
>
> Now go to play store, and try to install that app again.
>
> Check you have fixed your error.

Hope this helps!

Update:
Thanks Abhishek, you can also try uninstalling the app using adb:

`adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename`

Comment: Even uninstalling the package through ADB solves the problem :). You can add this in your answer. It will help others too.

Comment: Works with adb uninstall, but the -k option must not be used (-k: keep the data and cache directories around after package removal). Use adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename.

Comment: What phone you used? This problem occurred for me in Meizu M571H, but not in others phone model i used before. Maybe we can make the list of the problematic phone model

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem in this way:

1. Go to Settings > Apps
2. Find your app and open the **App Info**
3. Open the overflow menu (3 vertical dots)
4. Choose **Uninstall for all users**.

[image]

Comment: This is the answer that works for me because I've got a Guest user on my smartphone. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For **Redmi** or **Mi** Phones, the debug app was got installed on **second space**.

1. Go To **Setting -> Second Space -> Open Second Space**.
2. **Settings -> App - > downloaded app list**.
3. Click on the application, You want to **Uninstall**.
4. Click on **Uninstall**.
5. Back to First space from setting.

Or For Other Phones

1. Go to **settings -> apps -> downloaded app list**
2. You can see the **installed applications** in the list
3. Click on the Application
4. Click on **uninstall** for all users options.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow `adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename`
did not work for me. I am not sure if this was because I was on a lollipop device.

The answer suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250/you-cannot-install-this-app-because-another-user-has-already-installed-an-incom) did the trick. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to settings > apps > downloaded app list
- You can see the installed applications in the list (may be towards the very end)
- Click on the application,go to the menu option
- Click on uninstall for all users options