# "You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device"

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Trying to install my own app from play store, it says "You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device"

Note - I've uninstalled the debug version, and also cleared my Cache. Still can't get it to install from Play Store.

My phone is not rooted, so as another similar answer here on stackoverflow suggests, I cannot use a root file explorer to clear data.

Comment: @PreethiRao, yes, lollipop.

Comment: That's not Lollipop specific, but rather introduced in later versions of Google Play client. I am on KitKat (4.4.4) and have the same issue. For an explanation why, see DrZaphod's post below.

Comment: Just change your profile to guest or another if you have then uninstall it from all other users. And Voila ! ;)

Comment: The message can also be **Update package not compatible, please uninstall and then reinstall. You can install this app in App Store.** and mean the same thing.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

Refer this ,
Actually your debug version of the app didnt get uninstalled properly

1. Go to **settings > apps > downloaded app list**
2. You can see the **installed applications** in the list
   (the application may not be in order. or may be towards the very end)
3. Click on the application,go to the overflow menu option
4. Click on **uninstall** for all users options

Comment: This is it. Thank you! Is this Lollipop specific? Also, are the users who are using the previous version of my app going to have this issue?

Comment: Ha this is lollipop specific ,and  other users may not get this issue. cause they will be installing it as update of previous app,

Comment: @stack- its from lollipop, and none of your user will be facing it as this occurs due to different signing key

Comment: i guess this answer will be upvoted so many times in the future ;)

Comment: Note: it may be last in the list. I had a weird situation where I uninstalled it from all users, but it still showed up at the bottom of the "installed applications" list, with the label "app not installed" (btw, great UX google). Check the bottom if the list if you don't see it in alphabetical order.

Comment: Although apps are listed alphabetically, scroll to the last, here you find another alphabetically list of such apps. one reason of this is because you are installing it from adb.

Comment: This didn't work in my case!. Go to - settings - apps - all .... search for app then uninstall for all users

Comment: thanks it really worked, wondering why this problem occured!!

Comment: This solution has spared me many hours. I literally had 5 different user accounts on my phone I went through and uninstalled the app from. I received the same error even after doing that manually. This solution fixed it!

Comment: This solution is wokrs, In Android8 You have go Settings->Storage ->Other Apps-> <find your app> ->press "i" icon -> App Info open -> click right side on action bar -> press "Uninstall for all users" now app is uninstall and install your apk, your app is able to install... Happy Release :)

Comment: Was facing this in Pie, after I built my app on my phone from Android studio and then after uninstalling it, was trying to install from Play Store. This worked very well

Comment: This is another solution: Check if your device has "Second Space" like Xiaomi devices. Or check if you have installed dual apps. Unistall this founded aditional app.

Comment: @JotaPardo Holy hell. Thank you for mentioning this. 2 hours of wasted time was due to this.

Comment: What if it isn't in the list?

Comment: I'm using xiaomi. @JotaPardo your solution helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 172):

In my case I wasn't able to see the application in **settings > apps > downloaded app list** because I have already tried to uninstall it.


What worked for me was: `adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename`


I think my problem was because somehow I had installed the app on the Primary and Guest user and couldn't uninstall them from neither one.

Comment: yes,  only adb shell pm uninstall com.packagename helped me. And I can't see my application in settings. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I need. This worked for me too.

Comment: That command worked for me, I did not see the options explained in the accepted answer

Comment: I found that the app in question was installed on the guest account so uninstalled there to fix.

Comment: In my case, I had installed my application in Work Profile using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951666/install-apk-in-work-profile-via-adb-in-android . But the app was not visible in Work Profile. Then I tried to install again in personal profile. Though adb install myapp.apk shows success, application icon is not visible. Finally, this option worked for me.

Comment: NOTE: this works even if you don't see your package listed with this command: adb shell pm list packages

Comment: This one worked for me on realme norzo 5g.Thank you.

Comment: This one worked for me on an Android 12 device - I had been testing an app via both USB debugging and Play Store beta.

Comment: In my case the issues is with the 'MS Teams' app, I didn't do any secondary installs, But when i try install it from work profile 'the same error pops in', as to check uninstalled the installation from default/personal profile. Now in both play stores same error, Any thoughts ?

Comment: it worked for me but how can we prevent this as I face this issue on same application if I try to change package name and install while other applications are working fine. installing APK directly causes this problem, what could be the possible prevention?

Answer (score 42):

In Redmi note3,  the debug version of app was got installed on second space.
So Settings->Second space->Go to Second space. 
Uninstall the app.

Comment: it should work for everyone that created second space, awesome thanks!

Comment: I had to delete second space and then it worked. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks!!!!. Sneaky Second Space has hidden my app. 

Answer (score 21):

If you are reading this than probably you tried everything (ie. uninstall,clean cache,clean second space etc which you can do in phone) and  your problem is  still not resolved.
I faced the same issue and took me a day to figure it out.
But I found solution end of the day.
Here is what you have to do.

1.Open your app in android studio
2.Click on `gradle`(on right side corner)
3.go to `app`->`task`->`install`->`uninstallAll`
4.Click on `uninstallAll`
5.Boom problem solved!!!

**For cross platform app such as flutter**

If you are coming from cross platform such as flutter or react native, You will not see `gradle`menu. To get that
a)  go to `Android` folder then `app` .
b)  open `build.gradle` file,
c)  click on `Open for Editing in Android Studio`.
d)  you should see `gradle`.Now you can follow step 3

Comment: Thanks man!!! This works for me, I've been looking for a solution since last night!

Comment: I don't understand step 2.  Where is "gradle?"  Is that an icon?

Comment: Pete I assume you are coming from cross platform. I have updated the post. Please check.

Answer (score 19):

If using from Android Studio `2.3` (and maybe above versions), at last step of `Generate Signed APK` window, in `Signature versions:` part, check both check boxes, then click `Finish` to generate APK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!! I kept thinking it was because of something I had done in the manifest

Answer (score 14):

**Tried to check the above solutions but didn't help me.**

Finally I followed the below steps to over come on My device( Asus Zenfone 2)

Settings> Users> 1. Owner 2. Guest

Clicked on Guest> Playstore> Uninstall the application(Option came up once you search for that application)

> After un-installing went back to Owner(User) from Guest.
>   Was able to install the application successfully.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The error message should better specify what it means by 'user'. I thought it was referring to my Play Store user accounts, not my phone user accounts.

Answer (score 13):

I used a USB cable, then I run this command in Terminal `sudo adb uninstall` `packagename` something like `com.example.appname`.

Comment: So, after running that command did it work?

Comment: I removed the no-success story part. The remaining is quite short on explanation and might not be perceived as a helpful answer. Please consider rephrasing it by [edit]ing to add an explanation of how and why this helps.

Comment: Yeah that's what I only did and it worked fine.

Comment: Life Saver. Nice!

Answer (score 10):

**I have Fixed this issue on xiomi mobiles.**

The issue is because your app is already exist in parallel space or (Second Space).

1. Go to your settings
2. Find second space and press enter.
3. Switch to second space mode.
4. Once you enter. you can see your app there.
5. Unistall your app and switch back to second space.
6. Open playstore now you can download app easily.

Comment: @ManiruzzamanAkash welcome bro. vote up this answer if you didn't.

Answer (score 7):

Since lollipop it looks like the app preferences are associated with the signing key. Since the debug version of the app uses a different signing key, you have to completely uninstall the old debug app, including data.

To do this:

1. Open settings.
2. Choose app.
3. Is should default to the downloaded app list in alphabetical order.
4. You will find the uninstalled applications are not in alphabetical order but actually at the bottom of the list.
5. Click on the application
6. Choose 'Clear Data'

Note - most of this information is the same as another answer by [Preethi Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2590952/preethi-rao) but my edits have been rejected - also I have zero reputation so cannot actually comment.

Answer (score 6):

For **Redmi** or **Mi** Phones, the debug app was got installed on **second space**.

1. Go To **Setting -> Second Space -> Open Second Space**.
2. **Settings -> App - > downloaded app list**.
3. Click on the application, You want to **Uninstall**.
4. Click on **Uninstall**.
5. Back to First space from setting.

[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) [redmi](/questions/tagged/redmi) [redminote3](/questions/tagged/redminote3) [app](/questions/tagged/app)

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution for my Meizu pro 6.

**Settings -> Fingerprint and security -> Guest Mode -> Clear guest data**

Answer (score 4):

**Honor Device Solution**

I needed to uninstall it from private space too. 
You can open private space from

**Setting > Security & Privacy > Private Space**

Then open private space, and go to setting>apps then delete app from there.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** to [Preethi Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250/you-cannot-install-this-app-because-another-user-has-already-installed-an-incom/28853407#28853407)'s Answer.

From Android O this option is available under

**Settings > Apps & Notifications > App info**

There you can see your uninstalled debuggable app with label `Not installed for this user`.

You can open it now, and you can see triple vertical dot in top right corner.

In that there is option **Uninstall for all users**. By taping it you can uninstall the app completely.

Comment: it works. i have android orio API27. MIA1 Stock android os.

Answer (score 3):

On Samsung Galaxy TAB S2, Android 7.0, after clicking on `setting -> Apps` and then clicking on the app for which the error was displayed, I clicked on the 3 dots at the top right and there is an option there "uninstall of all users"

Answer (score 2):

**In Android API 25+**

Steps (Stock android os) :

Settings->  Storage ->Other Apps->  -> clear cache and data ->press "i" icon -> App Info open -> click right side on action bar -> press "Uninstall for all users"

now app is uninstall and install your apk, your app is able to install...

Happy Release :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change your profile to guest or another if you have then uninstall it from all other users.

And Voila ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a developer. Goto adb terminal and do `adb uninstall "package name of the app"`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a Xiaomi device when i had a debug APK previously installed and try to install the release one from playstore. Even after uninstalling the app, playstore still showed that error, i reeboted cleared cache, but everything got failed. At last i found the solution by going through playstore settings -> my apps and notifications -> library -> where you can see all your installed files directory. Remove your app from that list and try again. Now the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices has the option to log in as a "guest", try login into that guest account and see if you can locate and delete the problematic app.
Typically check on
Settings->Users->Multiple users

Answer (score 1):

When I go to download the app from the app store after deleting the debug app, I get this alert. I couldnt fix that through my device. So, I connected my device to my laptop and ran this command to find the package name.

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Next, I uninstalled it again with this command

```
adb shell pm uninstall myAppPackageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have a framework that has to install with your app, and that is what is actually erring. If you use xamarin, phone gap or any other development platform, make sure to go to installed apps and uninstall the framework.

I have seen this very often with Xamarin

Comment: Nope. It's a native Android app.

Comment: Any dependencies? Even native could have frameworks to install

Answer (score 0):

In **Android Lollipop** there are user, so this message mean that you need to switch the user and uninstall the app from all the users in the device...

**See in Settings->Users**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I couldn't install the app because I had it installed on a different user on the device. So deleting the app from that user fixed the problem on my end

Answer (score 0):

The existing app should be un-installed by going to settings-> Apps->...you may find the message that "this application is not installed for this user". Such apps can not be installed in the current user. If that is the case then, change the user/profile and then try to uninstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

For `Updated Android Studio 2.3` or upcoming...

1. `Build` > Generate `Signed apk`.
2. Create `Keystore path`.
3. Put `Password, alias, key password`.
4. `Build type` select accordingly(eg to release in playstore use `release`).
5. `Signature Version` select both `V1` and `V2` checkboxes.
6. after you click on `Finsih`.
7. Wait for `gradle` building.
8. After `gradle build` Android Studio will show you a `notification` to open the apk location explorer.
9. Go to `explorer` where you selected for the apk to store and you will see your .apk file name as `app-release.apk` use it.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If You Know Android Development

Then you can simple uninstall this app by adb.

adb uninstall packagename
exa: adb uninstall com.sdcardprefer

Here com.sdcardprefer is packagename.

This adb command remove incompatible version of the app that install in your devices.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, since I installed "Workspace" from google, the old app was installed inside the workspace. So, I need to go to "Workspace" then uninstall that old app from there first.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my app, but the play store was still giving me the error message that the app was still installed. Even though the additional users option was disabled, another profile on my device (Samsung Galaxy Tab A) still had the app installed which blocked my app from being re-installed.

Enable the users option in **Settings > Accounts and backup > Users**.

On my device, a Guest profile was present; I deleted it, but I imagine uninstalling the app on that profile would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went to my phone setting and deleted the Guest user and then turned off Multiple Users option after that I was able to download my deployed app from playstore, as well as build and run the react native app which was failing, hope it helps someone in future.