# Why can't I open my app when I install the release-apk? (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am quite new to app-development, and I ran into this problem after finishing my first app. Everything works fine when I launch it from android-studio, but when I build a release-apk and move it to my phone to install it (which works fine), I find no possibility to open it. The open button in the installing-screen is disabled and there is no entry in the app-menu on my phone. 
Here is my Manifest.xml, I hope that helps:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="@string/filter_title_rchat" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/chatActivityHeader"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>


    <activity android:name=".activities.SignupActivity"/>
</application>
```

I found several people with a similar problem, however they all seem to have forgotten the

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

part. Also I read that multidex might be a reason for the problem, but in my research i did not find anything more specific on that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You did enable install from unknown sources?

Comment: Yes it's enabled. I think otherwise i could not install it.

Comment: Could you take a look at this? Might be similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491954/2725502

Comment: You should use release apk to post in the playstore, if you just want to use the APK you should build apk, and then you will get the app-debug.apk, which probably will work.

Comment: Try rebuilding after removing `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />` from your manifest.

Comment: I want to release the app, I just want to test the release-version before putting it into the playstore. I also tried a rebuilt apk after removing the named rows, it still cannot be opened. Edit: Installation still works, I just can't open it.

Comment: I also saw the Question you mentioned before @ImAtWar, none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: Can you install & use the debug apk?

Comment: Yes, starting the debug apk works (at least from android studio)

Comment: Try to put it as alpha or beta testing in your console developer account

Comment: I tried, to be completely honest thats how I realized it does not work and came to the understanding that release versions should be tested before the actual release :D

Comment: Are you sure it is installed? Could you please check if the installer really says it is installed? Error message looks very similar to success message (if you don't expect it to fail then it's easy to miss the difference - I got caught by this a few times)

Comment: Yes it is definitely installed. I just checked again.

Comment: For everyone interested: I fixed it by moving `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />` into a different `<intent-filter>` section. The suggestion @Lal made did not work for me though. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @NotAName That was what I too was telling.. ;)

Comment: Different i<ntent-filters> cannot be grouped, they must be seperated. I also had a problem like this with NDEF intent but thanks to your post, I have fixed it.