# The issue with installing a signed apk to the phone

Tags: android, apk

I have some strange problem with installing a signed apk to the phone. The application installed without any problem by android studio also when I upload generated apk file to the google store I can install this application from there. But the same apk that I uploaded to google store I can not install from the phone. This problem does not occur on all phones. On the phones huawei 5.1, htc 4.4 is not installed but on xiaomi 5.1 without any problem.

Here my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'com.package.app'
            keyPassword 'keyPassword'
            storePassword 'storePassword'
            storeFile file('../android.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 23
        versionName '1.1.5'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
    ...
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help. Regards!

**EDIT**

After crash in logcat I saw follow exception:

```
Process: com.android.packageinstaller, PID: 7426
                                                 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 65351068 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 57MB until OOM
                                                     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:679)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
                                                     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:993)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2744)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2633)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:913)
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:872)
                                                     at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getAppSnippet(PackageUtil.java:205)
                                                     at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.initView(InstallAppProgress.java:495)
                                                     at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.onCreate(InstallAppProgress.java:401)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6151)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:188)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1539)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
```

I was already tried add `android:largeHeap="true"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`. Also in build.gradle I tried

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}
```

But still no result. I don't know why it's happens. In my code I'm not working with BitmapFactory and even if I remove all large images from project it still crashes.

Comment: Is there any  error message? Also was there older version(or newer) already installed?

Comment: Thanks for reply. On huawei installer just closes without any error notifications. On HTC - An unexpected application stopped "Package Installer". No, older  version is not installed

Comment: "when I upload generated apk file to the google store I can install this application from there. But the same apk that I uploaded to google store I can not install from the phone."

-> Can you please elaborate it properly?

Comment: @PratikPatel 1. Generated apk file; 2.a. uploaded to google store; 3.a. installation on any phone without any problems.
But! 2.b. upload apk file on phone; 3.b. Run installer -> Crash.
Sorry for my english, but I don't know how to explain it better( Regards!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737714/can-not-install-my-own-generated-apk/33911634#33911634

Comment: @X3Btel Thanks for the link, but already tried :(