# android install parse error

Tags: android, parsing, installation

I have generated apk using android studio IDE in release mode with both checkbox enabled(signature).
build.gradle file has the following entry

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

I am able to download and install in kitkat version mobile(4.4) but not in marshmallow version mobile(6.0.1). Getting the message - "Parse error. There was a problem while parsing the package." But when I connect usb to install in 6.0.1 version device, its getting installed.

Please help if I am missing anything.

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266270/3434561 and make sure that you've cleared all caches and old data on previous installations.

Comment: yes I am doing that but still getting the same error. Tried some other solutions as well like increase version code etc but of no help.