# Intant Run works, but .APK file does not install

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, apk

Well, the problem that is running when my application runs instantly the application runs perfectly on my smartphone. However, I can not install the same app through the APK.

Using Android Studio 3.2.0.0

Note: the APK is generated without errors, but at the same time can install appears: The app was not installed.

This is my build.grad (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        buildTypes {
            release {
                shrinkResources false
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
        api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        api 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
        api 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
        api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
        api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

Comment: What version is your device running on? Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34265897/2745495)?

Comment: My device is Android 8.1. Complement my question with my build.gradle (app), maybe it will be useful to find an answer to my problem