# Android: app not installed for release type

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signature, signing

I have generated `.apk` file by `V1` and `v2` signature

This file installed on my device successful

But if i uninstall application and i want install again, i get `app not installed` error

In summary, first install work fine, but after uninstall i can't install application again

> Note: `debug` type does not have this problem. This problem only for `release` type

Comment: goto Settings>All apps>search for your app. if there goto option>Uninstall for all user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install signed apk to device manually, got error "App not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265897/cannot-install-signed-apk-to-device-manually-got-error-app-not-installed)

Comment: @ShubhamVala i have 12000 users, i cant tell them for it

Comment: Your user will update application(Re install). They will not uninstall/install application. So they do not have to do it.

Comment: @ShubhamVala on lg g4 i cant find uninstall for all user

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla my users installed unsigned version :(

Comment: change your versionCode , versionName in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I create `new key store ( new sign )` and solved the problem

Comment: but I need to use same keystore, as its an update :(