# Cannot install my same signed apk twice in android device

Tags: android

Always showing app not installed, I have uninstalled it from every where in device

I have done all the answers given in stack overflow like

1. Uninstall apk for all users by going in setting->Apps->click on your  app->click overflow menu button and uninstall for all users.
2. Do minify enabled false
3. Change version code and install
4. Do allow backup false in manifest

Comment: You should add some more details on your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install signed apk to device manually, got error "App not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265897/cannot-install-signed-apk-to-device-manually-got-error-app-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you have more than one account on your android phone, like having an active `guest` account.

You need to login into the other account and uninstall application from that account too.

Comment: I have checked it it is not an issue