# Can't install my signed release apk on my own mobile phone

Tags: android, gradle, installation, apk, release

I'm trying to get my apk (release mode) right on my own device, but it says **"App not installed"** almost at the end of the progress. I thought that may be a problem of my own device, but I also tried in different ones of various versions of Android and the only one which works is a GalaxyS8 (version 8.0.0).

I've already tried: - **Selecting both V1 and V2 checkboxes in Signature Versions**;
- **Disabling PLAY Protect**;
- **Using minifyEnabled false**;

Nothing work out.

I saw a solution that says to **"Unistall for all users"**, but my app doesn't reach the 100%, the error appears almost at the end of the progress... so I don't get it. Another one suggests to increase the number of `versionCode`, but I don't get it as well.

Do you know another solution that might help?
Here's my gradle:

[image]

Comment: Did you try some solutions from this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265897/cannot-install-signed-apk-to-device-manually-got-error-app-not-installed

Comment: Yes. Basically those are the solutions that I've already tried. @DmitroIvanov

Comment: Use Android File Transfer, by which you can transfer your apk to USB connected device directly and then install that apk. It works for me.

Comment: Doesn't works, same error. @Raj

Comment: In my case solution was: uninstall app from guest(other)-account. I uninstall app from device like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266270/2289835) and app disappeared. but somehow I was able to show in guest-account apps. Each device can vary setting for it.

Comment: You must know that you can't install debug application on release, release on debug, debug on installed application from play strore , and release on installed application from playstore. try to delete gradle and rebuild the project. try to change the key store file and see if it install

Comment: Any information you could share from the logcat during the installation?

Comment: How can I acess to logcat, @Pierre? The only think that appears is "App not installed"...

Comment: How can I delete the gradle and then rebuild? @OussemaAroua

Comment: delete the gradle folder, and go to build menu the rebuild project