# Release application cannot installed after debug application installed device

Tags: android

App not installed

I have a device for android and I debug the application on this.
After I generate signed apk, I uninstall existing debug the application, try to install signed apk, But I got application not installed error.
I installed on a new device that does not have debug app installation, It looks ok.I tried clear app data and uninstall but does not work.

[Image eerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q35RT.png)

Comment: did you integrate facebook login/share?

Comment: Can you post full error text?

Comment: do you have multiple profile in your device ? e.g Guest

Comment: @TouhidulIslam I does not integrate, I edited error screen in my question. I dont have multi profile.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42780624/4659743

Comment: @PalPhoo can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

if build is not signed then you need to make sure both builds ie release and debug should be built from same device otherwise it gets conflicted.

You need to append versionName suffix to each build type you are having in your build.gradle file .This is to avoid conflicting package name,Suppose if you have one build type as debug then :

```
debug{
.......
.......

versionNameSuffix "_debug"   

.......
.......

    }
```

Same can be done for other versions.