# Install APK in Work Profile via ADB in Android

Tags: android, adb, android-for-work

Let's say we have a Work Profile (Android For Work) enabled in Android device. Does anyone know how to install an APK via ADB in Work Profile rather than personal profile.

I have seen the ADB documentation and there's a way to get the User ID but using the same ID I am unable to install an APK.

To get ID : `adb shell pm list users`
Install command : `adb install -r --user 12 app_name.apk`

Error message :

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install app-prodDebug.apk: Security exception: Shell does not have permission to access user 12
 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:22541 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:3989 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:2434

java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 12
 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:22541 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:3989 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellComma
```

Any way to get around this ? My use case here is to replace an App with debug option enabled so that I can troubleshoot any issue that is happening with that specific app which is installed in work profile.

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
adb push android.apk /data/local/tmp
adb shell pm install --user 12 /data/local/tmp/android.apk
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, This works. However in Samsung devices seems to have some issue.

Comment: says success but  app not seen

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the same SecurityException in the question.

Comment: Tried in Samsung S10, it says success, but cannot find the app.

Comment: to get the user id `adb shell pm list users`

Comment: This doesn't work on Android Pixel running Android 13

Answer (score 5):

- Above solution from @jtmcodle works fine.
- But to findout userid please use below command
- `adb shell dumpsys user`
- In my case above command gave following output
- `UserInfo{11:10100030} serialNo=11`
- So I ran below command to make it work
- `adb shell pm install --user 12 /data/local/tmp/android.apk`

Comment: I guess you ment `11` as user, that gives me an error `android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: not an approved installer`.

Answer (score 2):

According Android Developer site, if you install an app via usb with `adb` command, it will be installed in both profiles:

[Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles)

> If you manually install an app over a USB cable to a device which has a work profile, the app is installed on both the personal and the work profile. Once you have installed the app, you can test the app under the following conditions:

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148545/1667216) doesn't work, then invoke the following command from your DPC before you run those 2 steps:

```
devicePolicyManager.clearUserRestriction(componentName,UserManager.DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES
```

where 'componentName' is the ComponentName of the class that extends DeviceAdminReceiver.

Comment: and how or where do I do this? How do I know the adminName? Shouldn't a user not be able to disable such feature for security reasons (very interesting if I can though).

Comment: @CularBytes, I updated my comment. Does it make sense now?

And the disabling is done by the DPC, so essentially it's the EMM provider that will be invoking the code via an administrative policy, not the end user.