# Instant Enabled App Bundle Not Downloading Full APK instead shows error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to build the **instant enabled app bundle** by following [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle) article.

But when I click on **install app button** it shows the following message:

> **You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device.**

But when I clear(remove) the instant app from the phone then I'm able to download the APK.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250/you-cannot-install-this-app-because-another-user-has-already-installed-an-incom) StackOverflow thread but **no other app is installed** for **any** of the **accounts**.

Error message image attached below:

[image]

Can anyone help?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was doing a silly mistake.

I installed the **instant app in debug mode** from the android studio so that's why it is showing this error.

When I created a **build release** and **uploaded** it to the **play store** then it was **working** fine.