# Android unable to completely uninstall package (or corrupted package)

Tags: android, adb, package-managers

## Problem Description

So I was using Discord on my Android phone and decided to reinstall the app for personal reasons.

I uninstalled it from the "Settings" app and it seemed alright. I tried to reinstall it from Google play, and it alerts me with the message "You cannot install this app because another user has already installed an incompatible version on this device". I was not able to install it.

As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853250)(28853250) StackOverflow answer as well as some other resources I could find online, the app wasn't fully uninstalled in all users.

But since I don't have multi-user settings on my phone, I couldn't do anything to it.
Discord doesn't show up on the settings app, and neither on `pm list packages`

[image: Shell result for listing packages]

## Steps I have tried

Install using an APK file. Did not work. (Alerts "App not installed")

Reboot. Did not work.

System update (Those entire system updates by Samsung). Did not work.

I tried the following commands:

```bash
# adb shell through USB debug.

$ pm uninstall com.discord
# Result: Freezes and had to ^C to exit

$ pm uninstall -k com.discord
# Result: Freezes and had to ^C to exit

$ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.discord
# Result: Failure [not installed for 0]
# User id for 1 to 100 shows the same.

$ pm uninstall -k --user -1 com.discord
# Result: Freezes and had to ^C to exit
```

[image: Shell Result for tried commands]

Installed using an APK file using adb:

```bash
# In my linux computer
$ adb install discord.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install discord.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.discord signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

[image: shell result for installing apk using adb]

## Some hint maybe?

An interesting behaviour happened after executing commands stated in the Steps tried section, the android shell seems to freeze.

I was not able to exit the shell using the `exit` command, which clearly worked without executing those commands.

[image: exit does not work]

Comment: Have you installed Discord app from Google Play before as well?

Comment: Yea, i am pretty sure the one i uninstalled was from google play

Comment: Have you tried `adb install -r discord.apk`? It should delete existing data. If your device already has `cmd` command you can try `cmd package list package -u` which lists all installed app including uninstalled (where only app data is still installed).

Comment: Yes, when i use the `-r` flag when using adb install, it shows the same as without using the flag. The `cmd package list package -u` command does shows `package:com.discord` when I grep discord.